Power-Automate flow not being triggered by webhook events, intermittently
We are at a loss.
We have a flow that is subscribed to an external application.  The external application sends call events (from a call center) through a HTTP payload.
We use the "When HTTP Request received" trigger to receive the payload, and start the flow.
We seem to be missing some payloads.
Here is a normal, successful example:

Payload 1: inbound call is queued
Payload 2: inbound call is connected
Payload 3: inbound call ends

But, we are seeing cases where there is no end to the call, when we know the call ended.  This is confusing our downstream logic.  We reach out to the external application support, and they show evidence that they did send the "call ends" payload.
Where is this failing?  What can we check?  Need guidance of how we could measure this failure, since the flow seems to not be triggered.
Thanks

You got any trigger conditions? If not, best to raise it with Microsoft.

We suspect the problem is/was server memory.  We moved PowerAutomate (and its Gateway) to its own server.
